# How to start a dynamic backend using a cron scheduled request in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, backend

I'm trying to initiate a dynamic backend using a cron task, however after I deploy I don't see the new cron task under the cron tab and also I don't see any instances of backends under my backend tab. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Now the cron job runs properly (after I changed the schedule to "every 1 minutes". However the backend refuses to run. The cron tab says `on time Failed`. Maybe I need to define some handler in my app.yaml or something like that?

EDIT2: After using appcfg to update the backends list I can see the backend I defined under backends tab. Now I just have to wait and see if it works (does anybody know of a way to make a get request to the backend with the browser? I don't want to wait an hour just to see if it's running (the cron task runs every hour now).

### My code

My cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: crawler backend activation
  url: /crawl
  target: crawler
  schedule: every minute
```

My backends.yaml file:

```
backends:
- name: crawler
  class: B1
  instances: 1
  start: crawler.application
  options: dynamic
```

My backend handler crawl.py:

```
import logging
import webapp2 as webapp

class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    logging.debug('crawler started')



application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/crawl', Handler)])
```

Comment: Why would you set up a dynamic backend, then ping it every minute?

Comment: @NickJohnson Just trying to make it run code. Sort of a "hello world" attempt.

Comment: It's a very strange thing to want to do. If you want to test cron, just point it at a regular frontend instance. If you want to test backends, don't use cron.

Comment: Why? Eventually I'm trying to set up a backend that is run by a cron job. I want to have it run every hour and do some crawling work. I just did it evey minute so I could see if it's running. Is there any way I can force the backend to run? Say by pointing my browser to `crawler.my-app.appspot.com/crawl` or something like that? Maybe I can force the cron task to run somehow?

Comment: Why not use the task queue, if you want to run something every hour? There's not much reason to be using a backend here.

Comment: Because it's not just something, it's a crawl task, and I want it to be done by a backend instance and not one of my frontends instance for better resources management.

Comment: You do realise that frontends will be spun up as necessary to handle traffic? Using a backend for this will not give you 'better resource management' - but it will cost you more, as the instance spun up just for this task waits around for 15 minutes to see if you want it to do anything else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11555/discussion-between-uri-and-nick-johnson)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. To me a backend is simply 10-9 more hours of free work I can do. My frontend instance hours are depleted too fast and this will give me more resources. Furthermore it will be easier to maintain than breaking the task into small parts to be performed by the frontends. I thought this is exactly the kind of stuff backends are used for, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code. First, your startup handler is called `crawl.py`, but your `backends.yaml` refers to `crawler.py`. Second, the startup handler specified in `backends.yaml` only specifies the handler file for the start request - all other requests, such as those created by cron, go through `app.yaml` and are routed to handlers like regular requests.

Comment: ok I changed it to `start: crawl.application`. Could I just change the cron job to point to the target and have the url '\'?
What about this line - `application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/crawl', Handler)])`? How will it have to change?

Comment: That will still only work for the start handler - for handling other requests, like the cron one to `/crawl`, you need to map the handlers through `app.yaml`.

Comment: ok I added this to app.yaml: `- url: /crawl script: crawler.application`. I don't need to use `login: admin`, as every admin is private by default right? Anything else I need to change?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "every admin is private by default". If you don't add access control of some sort - `login:admin`, or checks in your handler - users will be able to hit the handler themselves.

Comment: Sorry I meant every backend can be accessed only from within the app by default.

Comment: Yes, but handlers defined in `app.yaml` can be accessed by users.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this cron format:

```
schedule: every 1 minutes
```

Note: if you call dynamic backend every minute, it's never going to shut down, as AFAIK the shutdown delay is 15 mins. In this case you might want to use resident backends.

Comment: I'm still getting `on time Failed` on the cron tab, but no errors appear on the log... :(

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I was missing - apparently the regular deploy commands don't update the backends, so I needed a new batch file to do this:

```
echo <password> | python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" --email=<myemail> backends <app src folder path> update
```